# Node file modes on Windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, filesystems

In [Node](http://nodejs.org/), file modes (e.g. for [fs.open](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback)) are defined [in the terms of the POSIX world](http://mason.gmu.edu/~montecin/UNIXpermiss.htm) (a three-digit octal value). However, that does not map to how Windows does things. Windows does not have such tight coupling between user permissions and the filesystem. Windows' [`OpenFile` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not even have any related parameters. But from what I gathered so far, they are not entirely ignored either.

Is there any explanation on how to use Node file modes on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [the source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/uv/src/win/fs.c#L459). It seems like the only thing they are doing is setting FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY based on whether the file is writeable or not.

```
  if (flags & _O_CREAT) {
    if (!((req->mode & ~current_umask) & _S_IWRITE)) {
      attributes |= FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY;
    }
  }
```

The notes on fs.chmod are interesting as well.

```
  /* Todo: st_mode should probably always be 0666 for everyone. We might also
   * want to report 0777 if the file is a .exe or a directory.
   *
   * Currently it's based on whether the 'readonly' attribute is set, which
   * makes little sense because the semantics are so different: the 'read-only'
   * flag is just a way for a user to protect against accidental deleteion, and
   * serves no security purpose. Windows uses ACLs for that.
   *
   * Also people now use uv_fs_chmod() to take away the writable bit for good
   * reasons. Windows however just makes the file read-only, which makes it
   * impossible to delete the file afterwards, since read-only files can't be
   * deleted.
   *
   * IOW it's all just a clusterfuck and we should think of something that
   * makes slighty more sense.
   *
   * And uv_fs_chmod should probably just fail on windows or be a total no-op.
   * There's nothing sensible it can do anyway.
   */
```

Comment: Really interesting! Question is: What is the value for `_S_IWRITE`? Which of the three values does it check? Owner, group or other? It's not defined by uv.

Comment: Based on the source it maps to S_IWUSR which maps to Owner.

Comment: Ok, that finally narrows it down: On Windows, everything but the owner's write flag is ignored. And omitting it only causes chaos. Gotcha!