# How do I grant permissions for fs module nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a program that needs to check if a folder exists. If it does - it deletes and creates it again (to clear it). If it doesn't - it creates it. After that I copy all paths that get returned from a function into that cleared folder. I'm currently running into errors for permssions to delete the folder and also errors for copying the file. I tried `chmodSync` but I couldn't work it out. Here's my code:

```js
function sortTracks(dir) {
    fs.chmodSync(
        path.join(dir, "playlist"),
        fs.constants.S_IRUSR | fs.constants.S_IWUSR
    );
    if (fs.existsSync(path.join(dir, "playlist")))
        fs.rmdirSync(path.join(dir, "playlist"));

    fs.mkdirSync(path.join(dir, "playlist"));

    fs.chmodSync(
        path.join(dir, "playlist"),
        fs.constants.S_IRUSR | fs.constants.S_IWUSR
    );
    getAllFiles(dir, []).forEach(track => {
        fs.chmodSync(track, fs.constants.S_IRUSR);
        fs.copyFileSync(track, path.join(dir, "playlist"));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I could tell, `sortTracks` attempts to:

1. Set the permissions of `${cwd}/playlist` to be readable and writeable by the user
2. Remove `${dir}/playlist` if it already exists
3. Create the `${dir}/playlist` directory
4. Set the permissions of `${dir}/playlist`, as done in step #2
5. For each file returned by `getAllFiles(dir, [])`:

   1. Set its permissions to be readable by the user
   2. Copy it to `${dir}/playlist`

A few things that stood out to me:

- Step #1 is redundant. You can see it for yourself - try running the following in bash:

  ```bash
  $ mkdir a
  $ chmod -rw a
  $ rm -rf a
  ```

  You'll see that `a` gets created and removed.
- Step #4 is redundant. The default permissions for a directory make it readable & writeable.
- Removing the directory should be done using:

  ```js
  fs.rmSync(path.join(dir, "playlist"), {recursive: true, force: true});
  ```

  Instead of `fs.rmdirSync` (see [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsrmdirsyncpath-options)).

I hope fixing these will resolve the issue for you.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the suggestions. These do seem to work but now I'm getting an error about the chmod that makes the track readable. The error is telling me that `The "mode" argument must be of type number. Received undefined` The reason for this is that the `fs.constants.S_IRUSR` return undefined and I don't know why.

Comment: @ProGamer2711 Which operating system and Node.js version are you using? `fs.constants` can be a bit different depending on the platform you're running in.

Comment: I'm using `Windows 10` with `node v16.6.2`

Comment: @ProGamer2711 See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23330010). In short, `chmodSync` doesn't really do anything relevant on Windows. Remove the calls to it from `sortTracks` and things should now work.

Comment: now I'm unable to delete the folder "playlist" and I'm still unable to copy the files. I was having this issue prior to adding chmods